# How to use ngoptions to generate an optgroup without repeating the group name

Tags: angularjs

Hello i'm trying to use ng-options to get a grouping of countries by region. It only works by repeating the group name in every row. Is it possible to do it using the following json :

```
 $scope.countries = [
               { region: "americas", countries: [{ value: "usa", key: "1" }, { value: "mexico", key: "2" }] },
               { region: "Africa", countries: [{ value: "3", key: "Algeria" }, { value: "4", key: "Morocco" }, { value: "5", key: "Tunisia" }] },
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-options` is pretty locked down in it's definition, so you'll probably need to loop through your countries array and add the region, something like:

```
$scope.countries_with_regions = [];
$scope.countries.forEach(function(region){
    region.countries.forEach(function(country){
        country.region = region.region;
        $scope.countries_with_regions.push( country );
    });
});
```

then you can do your `ng-options` with the `countries_with_regions`

Comment: This is similar to adding the region in every country , i thought there might be a different way with repeating it but thanks anyway

Comment: its exactly adding the region in every country, just like I said. I figured I would give you something useful other than No, or change the back-end which handles your data

Answer (score 0):

You data structure fo countries needs to be like

```
countries = [{value : 3, key: "algeria", region : "africa"}, ...]
```

for the ng-options to be able to "group by" region.